# What's $\kappa$ and $\kappa'$ for $K_{n,n}$ in graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory

What's $\kappa$ and $\kappa'$ for $K_{n,n}$ in graph theory?

Comment: You mean $\kappa$ and $\kappa'$ for the complete graph $K_n$ ?

Comment: To improve the question, not everyone is familiar with your notation (*or your spelling*).  Include please what "kapa" and "kapaprim" are supposed to represent in words.  Perhaps you mean $\kappa$, the [clique number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory#K), of the [complete bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_bipartite_graph) $K_{n,n}$.  (*I am more used to seeing clique number written as $\omega(G)$ instead*).  Perhaps instead you mean the [connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)) of the graph.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\kappa(G)$ be the biggest $k$ such that $G$ is $k$-connected and similarly $\kappa'(G)$ the biggest $k$ such that $G$ is $k$-edge-connected.

**Claim:** $\kappa(K_{n,n})=n$.

We get an upper bound if we remove all vertices of one side, which leaves us with $n$ isolated points, which are clearly not connected. Thus the graph is not $(n+1)$-connected, giving $\kappa(K_{n,n}) \le n$. For a lower bound remove any $n-1$ points of this graph. We have on both sides at least one vertex left (every side of $K_{n,n}$ has $n$ vertices), and all edges between these non empty sides.

**Claim:** $\kappa'(K_{n,n})=n$.

Note that for any graph $\kappa(G) \le \kappa'(G)$. So it remains to prove that $\kappa'(K_{n,n}) \le n$. This means that we need to find a set of $n$ edges which disconnects the graph. For this choose some vertex of $K_{n,n}$ and delete all his edges. Therefore this vertex is disconnected from the rest of the graph. Note that we deleted exactly $n$ edges.